# Generate random segments

Tags: modeling, python, scripting

I would like to have a guide to generate segments of length l distributed randomly without intersection in a defined square field. The end of the loop is fixed by the total length of the right generated. Grateful if someone could help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack is to run a rigid body simulation until you arrive at a frame which looks right. Writing a script to get what you need can be a bit of a puzzle...